# how to debugg truffle tests with built in debugger

Tags: truffle

So I'd like to use the commandline debugger in truffle.

To test I simply run `truffle test`

I have an empty truffle.js file.

I can get my transaction ID in the javascript tests.
When I run:

```
 truffle debug 0xce1bc402758bd7b6995d82430214c283967371ade97b01bd46e1fe074ea0a4c2
```

I get:

```
Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network.
```

I'm guessing this is because after the test ran truffle shut down the test network?

I know I could use testrpc, but it causes a lot of problems for me.

Is there a way to use truffle debug with their new built in test framework?

Thanks

*edit* 
When attempting to use testrpc I get this error message after every test case  : `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

this is my truffle.js

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 6712388
    }

  }
};
```

but when I comment out the development network, then truffle defaults to the "test" network and everything works fine.

*edit2* I should note that my tests take a lot of gas. So im guessing that the reverts are caused because an object that is expected to be there is not because I didn't have enough gas to deploy it. I tried increasing the gas limit in truffle.js but that fails with some other error...

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called "truffle.js".
In this file, you must specify the network you want to use.

Moreover, when running a command, you can specify the network to use:

More information [here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration)

Comment: my truffle.js is empty and truffle seems to default to using the network "test." If i try to specify my own address I get an error saying that it cant run due to gas fees...

Comment: Can you paste in your original post the exact error you get?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `ganache-cli`, the successor of `testrpc` (see [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#looking-for-testrpc) for more details)
2. Run `ganache-cli` as follows:

   ganache-cli --port=8545 --gasLimit=0xfffffffffff --account=0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef,1000000000000000000000000000000000000000

   If you need more than one account in your tests, then just add as many `--account=...` as you need (separated by space), and use a different key for each one of them.